# Using Rouché's theorem to find zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Let $f(z) = z + g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic. Suppose that $|Img(z)| < 1$ for $z \in [−1−i,1−i]\cup[−1+i,1+i]$ and $|Reg(z)| < 1$ for $z \in [−1−i,−1 + i]\cup[1−i,1 + i]$. Show that $f$ has exactly one zero on the square $Q = \{x + iy \in \mathbb C : |x| < 1,|y| < 1\}$.

I have been trying to find the appropriate function to compare to $g(x)$ in order to apply the theorem, the most obvious candidate would be the function $h(z) = z$. I can show that this function is greater than $g(z)$ on the corners of the square but not anywhere else.

Any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: An identical question was asked 5 minutes earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3650317/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $f$ has exactly one zero on the square $Q =$ {$x + iy ∈ C : |x| < 1, |y| < 1$}.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650317/show-that-f-has-exactly-one-zero-on-the-square-q-x-iy-%e2%88%88-c-x-1)